# Installing helper utility in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to build an app that needs to use an open-source command-line utility.  I've already established that I should use NSTask to run the utility from within my app once it is installed, but how can I go about installing the utility when I install the app?  I have the binary file.

Comment: Like @CarlVeazey says. NSTask is Mac OS X only. I don't know of any way for an iOS app to launch another executable, and I'd be astonished if there was a way to do it and still get your app approved for release in the App Store.

Comment: I actually did some research, the class is there (via `NSClassFromString`) and if you copy the NSTask.h header in apparently apps designed to be run on jailbreak phones can use it. That said, I don't think how to install software on a jailbroken phone is really on topic for SO.

Comment: If its open source, use the source (licence permitting) and build it into your app. Or look at how it works and code your own version in your app.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I'm trying to build in tcpdump, which only works if the phone is jailbroken anyways, so yes, I'm aiming for that and not to distribute via the appstore. I'm going to try @Wain's suggestion.